# Extract a value from a JSON string stored in a pandas data frame column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe with a column named *json2* which contains a json string coming from an API call:

`"{'obj': [{'timestp': '2022-12-03', 'followers': 281475, 'avg_likes_per_post': 7557, 'avg_comments_per_post': 182, 'avg_views_per_post': 57148, 'engagement_rate': 2.6848}, {'timestp': '2022-12-02', 'followers': 281475, 'avg_likes_per_post': 7557, 'avg_comments_per_post': 182, 'avg_views_per_post': 57148, 'engagement_rate': 2.6848}]}"`

I want to make a function that iterates over the column and extracts the number of *followers* if the *timestp* matches with a given date

```
def get_followers(x):
    if x['obj']['timestp']=='2022-12-03':
        return x['obj']['followers']

df['date'] = df['json2'].apply(get_followers)
```

I should get 281475 as value in the column *date* but I got an error: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key named **obj** occurs in list of dictionaries. Before you define another key, you must also specify the index of the list element.

```
import ast
df['json2']=df['json2'].apply(ast.literal_eval) #if dictionary's type is string, convert to dictionary.

def get_followers(x):
    if x['obj'][0]['timestp']=='2022-12-03':
        return x['obj'][0]['followers']

df['date'] = df['json2'].apply(get_followers)
```

Also you can use this too. This does the same job as the function you are using:

```
df['date'] = df['json2'].apply(lambda x: x['obj'][0]['followers'] if x['obj'][0]['timestp']=='2022-12-03' else None)
```

for list of dicts:

```
def get_followers(x):
    for i in x['obj']:
        if i['timestp'] == '2022-12-03':
            return i['followers']
            break
    
df['date'] = df['json2'].apply(get_followers)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is not working, I get "None" as result, but I presume this is because the date is not in the first element of the list of dictionaries.

Comment: if there are multiple dictionaries, a for loop can be created to search all dictionaries. Do you want me to edit the answer accordingly?

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! Big kudos!